# How to check offline if two FB user are mutual friends

Tags: facebook-fql

I need a query running in a CRONJOB that check if 2 FBuser are mutual friends:
something like the following, but I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT......) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad  Request in...
```

on the FBtool I get the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
"message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected '+' at position 6.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 601
 }
 } )
```

This is the script:

```
// get App AccessToken
$app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
 . "client_id=" . $appId
 . "&client_secret=" .$secret
 . "&grant_type=client_credentials";

    $response = file_get_contents($app_token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

  $App_access_token = $params['access_token'];

try { $permissions = $facebook->api('/'.$user1.'/permissions');
            } catch(Exception $o){  $log[] = "//***  error on   $user1/permissions > $o";   }
$permessi=$permissions[data][0];

if(array_key_exists('read_stream', $permessi) or array_key_exists('read_friendlists', $permessi) ) {

$fql_q = "SELECT 'uid1','uid2' FROM friend WHERE 'uid1'='$user1' AND 'uid2'='$user2'"; 
$fql_q = urlencode($fql_q); 
$fql_query_url = "https://graph.facebook.com"
  ."/fql?q=$fql_q"
  ."&access_token=$App_access_token";
 $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
if(is_array($fql_query_obj)){ 
$CountFriends = $CountFriends + 1;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual query that gives the syntax error in the Graph API Explorer? Btw., your query shown in your PHP code is definitively wrong, because you are treating column names as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends#readmodifiers

I hope could be helpfull
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook offline access has been deprecated
Follow this link:
[offline-access-removal](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal)